# How can I capture output and show it at the same time with Python?

Tags: python

I have a pretty long running job, which runs for several minutes and then gets restarted. The task outputs various information which I capture like this:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

The thing is, I will only get the entire output at a time. I would like to show output as the program is sending it to stdout, while still pushing it back in a buffer ( I need to check the output for the presence of some strings ). In Ruby I would do it like this:

```
IO.popen(cmd) do |io|
  io.each_line do |line|
    puts line
    buffer << line
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
cmd = ["./my_program.sh"]
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   # launch the process
while p.poll() is None:          # check if the process is still alive
    out = p.stdout.readline()    # if it is still alive, grab the output
    do_something_with(out)       # do what you want with it
```

Answer (score 3):

You could read it one line at a time:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('grep -ir graph .', stdout=PIPE)
while not p.returncode:
    s = p.stdout.readline()
    print s
    p.poll()
```

In this way, you are only blocking for the time it takes to process to output a single line.

Comment: Since you didn't specify a buffer size, a 4KB buffer will be added between the two processes, so they usually won't block each other.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "tee" command. It does exactly what you need from it.
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm

Comment: Yes, but I need to process the buffer in Python, to know if I should launch the task again.

Comment: the OP is asking about monitoring a process they launched using popen from inside Python code so this is not helpful.