# How do I write to a Python subprocess' stdin?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, nuke

I'm trying to write a Python script that starts a subprocess, and writes to the subprocess stdin. I'd also like to be able to determine an action to be taken if the subprocess crashes.

The process I'm trying to start is a program called `nuke` which has its own built-in version of Python which I'd like to be able to submit commands to, and then tell it to quit after the commands execute. So far I've worked out that if I start Python on the command prompt like and then start `nuke` as a subprocess then I can type in commands to `nuke`, but I'd like to be able to put this all in a script so that the master Python program can start `nuke` and then write to its [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) (and thus into its built-in version of Python) and tell it to do snazzy things, so I wrote a script that starts `nuke` like this:

```
subprocess.call(["C:/Program Files/Nuke6.3v5/Nuke6.3", "-t", "E:/NukeTest/test.nk"])
```

Then nothing happens because `nuke` is waiting for user input. How would I now write to standard input?

I'm doing this because I'm running a plugin with `nuke` that causes it to crash intermittently when rendering multiple frames. So I'd like this script to be able to start `nuke`, tell it to do something and then if it crashes, try again. So if there is a way to catch a crash and still be OK then that'd be great.

Comment: If you are looking to quickly write a string to a subprocess stdin, use `input` of [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run); e.g., `subprocess.run(['cat'], input='foobar'.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: How to write multiple times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616018/multiple-inputs-and-outputs-in-python-subprocess-communicate

Answer (score 126, accepted):

It might be better to use [`communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['myapp'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='data_to_write')[0]
```

"Better", because of this warning:

> Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Comment: aaah great, thanks fro that, also if i just do an import subprocess will i still need to import popen PIPE etc?

Comment: No, you don't, but then you need to reference them like `subprocess.PIPE`. This method also imports everything in the subprocess module. The `from subprocess import PIPE` introduces into the current namespace, so that you can use just `PIPE`.

Comment: the only problem im having wit this method is that the program freezes up whilst the process thinks, i would like it if the python script could launch the process and monitor its stdout from afar

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7977829/991521) regarding on processing smaller pieces of output. Alternatively, it sounds like something like a thread could help you if you want the execution without blocking your main thread.

Comment: thanks jro, do you know if there is there  way to keep the process open after the communicate, if for example i need to write to the stdin more than once?

Comment: The `communicate` method reads data until EOF is received. If you want to interact with the process dynamically, access the pipe using `p.stdin.write('data')`. For the reading, see my previous comment. The warning is about this way of communicating though, so take care you don't fill up the buffers. Easiest way to verify this, is to just try it...

Comment: thanks jro, im trying that now, running into problems with formatting strings for write() in python 3.x, getting there though, thanks again

Comment: For python 3.4 you need to do `p.communicate(input="data for input".encode())`

Comment: @jro I suppose you might have wanted to set the stdout parameter of `p` to `stdout=STDOUT`? Otherwise no need to import it.

Comment: When you're searching the answer for the question above, for example if you need to execute "ping" command and `communicate` doesn't do stick, this answer is utterly unhelpful.

Answer (score 23):

To clarify some points:

As [jro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991521/jro) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475367/1278994), the right way is to use `subprocess.communicate`.

Yet, when feeding the `stdin` using `subprocess.communicate` with `input`, you need to initiate the subprocess with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE too.

Also [qed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562222/qed) has mentioned in the comments that for Python 3.4 you need to encode the string, meaning you need to pass Bytes to the `input` rather than a `string`. This is not entirely true. According to the docs, if the streams were opened in text mode, the input should be a string (source is the same page).

> If streams were opened in text mode, input must be a string. Otherwise, it must be bytes.

So, if the streams were not opened explicitly in text mode, then something like below should work:

```py
import subprocess
command = ['myapp', '--arg1', 'value_for_arg1']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = p.communicate(input='some data'.encode())[0]
```

I've left the `stderr` value above deliberately as `STDOUT` as an example.

That being said, sometimes you might want the output of another process rather than building it up from scratch. Let's say you want to run the equivalent of `echo -n 'CATCH\nme' | grep -i catch | wc -m`. This should normally return the number characters in 'CATCH' plus a newline character, which results in 6. The point of the echo here is to feed the `CATCH\nme` data to grep. So we can feed the data to grep with stdin in the Python subprocess chain as a variable, and then pass the stdout as a PIPE to the `wc` process' stdin (in the meantime, get rid of the extra newline character):

```py
import subprocess

what_to_catch = 'catch'
what_to_feed = 'CATCH\nme'

# We create the first subprocess, note that we need stdin=PIPE and stdout=PIPE
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-i', what_to_catch], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# We immediately run the first subprocess and get the result
# Note that we encode the data, otherwise we'd get a TypeError
p1_out = p1.communicate(input=what_to_feed.encode())[0]

# Well the result includes an '\n' at the end, 
# if we want to get rid of it in a VERY hacky way
p1_out = p1_out.decode().strip().encode()

# We create the second subprocess, note that we need stdin=PIPE
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-m'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# We run the second subprocess feeding it with the first subprocess' output.
# We decode the output to convert to a string
# We still have a '\n', so we strip that out
output = p2.communicate(input=p1_out)[0].decode().strip()
```

This is somewhat different than the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129244/1278994), where you pipe two processes directly without adding data directly in Python.

Hope that helps someone out.

Answer (score 21):

Since `subprocess` 3.5, there is the [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20run#subprocess.run) function, which provides a convenient way to initialize and interact with `Popen()` objects. `run()` takes an optional `input` argument, through which you can pass things to `stdin` (like you would using `Popen.communicate()`, but all in one go).

Adapting [jro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991521/jro)'s example to use `run()` would look like:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(['myapp'], input='data_to_write', capture_output=True, text=True)
```

After execution, `p` will be a `CompletedProcess` object. By setting `capture_output` to `True`, we make available a `p.stdout` attribute which gives us access to the output, if we care about it. `text=True` tells it to work with regular strings rather than bytes. If you want, you might also add the argument `check=True` to make it throw an error if the exit status (accessible regardless via `p.returncode`) isn't 0.

This is the "modern"/quick and easy way to do to this.

Comment: Please note `text` appeared only recently, for compatibility with older versions you might need `input='data_to_write'.encode('utf-8')` instead

Comment: [@The Godfather](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657819/the-godfather) good point. The `text` kwarg was apparently introduced in 3.7. Given that `run()` itself was added in 3.5, it is true that Python 3.5 and 3.6 would have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

while `.communicate()` is the recommended way, it doesnot solve all usecases. For those who wants to write a stream of lines and read its transformation back from a subprocess, here is an example code.

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import itertools
import subprocess
import threading

def copy_to_stdin(proc, src_file: Path, mt_file: Path):
    """Example task: Write data to subproc stdin. 
      Note: run this on another thread to avoid deadlocks
    This function reads two parallel files (src_file and mt_file), and write them as TSV record to the stdin of the sub process.
    :param proc: subprocess object to write to
    :param src_file: path to source file
    :param mt_file: path to MT file
    """

    with src_file.open() as src_lines, mt_file.open() as mt_lines:
        for src_line, mt_line in itertools.zip_longest(src_lines, mt_lines):
            if src_line is None or mt_line is None:
                log.error(f'Input files have different number of lines')
                raise ValueError('Input files have different number of lines')
            line = src_line.rstrip('\n') + '\t' + mt_line.rstrip('\n') + '\n'
            proc.stdin.write(line)
    proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.close()    # close stdin to signal end of input


cmd_line = ['yourcmd', 'arg1']  # fill your args
src_file, mt_file = ... # your files

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_line, shell=False, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=sys.stderr, text=True, encoding='utf8', errors='replace') 
try:
    copy_thread = threading.Thread(target=copy_to_stdin, args=(proc, src_file, mt_file))
    copy_thread.start()
    # demonstration of reading data from stdout. 
    for line in proc.stdout:
        line = line.rstrip()
         print(line)
    
    copy_thread.join()
    returncode = proc.wait()
    if returncode != 0:
       raise RuntimeError(f'Process exited with code {returncode}')
finally:
    if proc.returncode is None:
        log.warning(f'Killing process {proc.pid}')
        proc.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

One can write data to the subprocess object on-the-fly, instead of collecting all the input in a string beforehand to pass through the communicate() method.

This example sends a list of animals names to the Unix utility sort, and sends the output to standard output.

```
import sys, subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('sort', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=sys.stdout)
for v in ('dog','cat','mouse','cow','mule','chicken','bear','robin'):
    p.stdin.write( v.encode() + b'\n' )
p.communicate()
```

Note that writing to the process is done via p.stdin.write(v.encode()).  I tried using
`print(v.encode(), file=p.stdin)`, but that failed with the message `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.  I haven't figured out how to get print() to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: On Python 3.10

add '-u' to subprocess.Popen, found it in a forum either here or somewhere else
add '\n' to whatever string before encoding and sending through stdin.write()

I was trying to open a separate python file, and have the contents of that file show up in a tkinter text box.

the GUI is one I wanted to use with many programs, so it opens up the program in a subprocess. from searching many different forums I have gotten it to work and I am placing my answer here to hopefully help someone along the way.

My GUI starts a thread that calls the subprocess.

```
def select_program_thread(self):
    self.select_program_thrd = Thread(target=self.select_program, daemon=True)
    self.select_program_thrd.start()
    self.master.update()

def select_program(self):
    program_select = filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension='.py', initialdir='\path\to\your\dir')
    self.program = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u',program_select], # needed the '-u' to allow constant printing to the text box, found in a comment on a similar post, but don't remember which thread or person
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    while self.program.poll() == None: # check whether process is still running
        try:
            line = self.program.stdout.readline()
            if line:
                msg = line.decode() # incoming is bytes, need to decode
                self.print_to_text(msg.strip()) 
                self.program.stdout.flush() # unsure if needed but overall was working so left it alone
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        
     self.program.wait()
```

Then when my program needs any input from the console i have a button that grabs the string and transforms it into bytes

```
def console_input(self):
    try:
        txt = (self.console_text_input.get() + '\n') # Needed to add the '\n' to actually send it through. got stuck otherwise
        self.console_text_input.delete(0, END) # clear entry widget
        msg = txt.encode() # change to bytes
        self.program.stdin.write(msg) # write to subprocess
        self.program.stdin.flush() # clear stdin
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Test file

```
from time import sleep
print('I started Successfully')
x=3
while x>0:
    print(x)
    sleep(1)
    x-=1
print('Please send a command to the console')
v = input()
print(f'you typed {v}')
sleep(1)
print('Finished, Program Over')
sleep(1) # needed for stdout to be read
```

I needed at least one second at the end of the program to allow the stdout to be read and put into the text box, otherwise the process terminates before it is captured.

Answer (score -2):

You can provide a file-like object to the `stdin` argument of `subprocess.call()`.

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for the `Popen` object applies here.

To capture the output, you should instead use `subprocess.check_output()`, which takes similar arguments. From the documentation:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```