# Output from a process

Tags: python, subprocess

I have to execute a command and store the output of it in file. The output spans multiple pages and i have to press enter multiple times to see the complete output( similar to that when a man returns multiple pages).  I am thinking of using the subprocess module, but how to provide input to the process, when the process prompts.

Comment: And which command would that be?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: No,I have to run -help on a utility, and it returns multiple pages.  Got it running . Thanks.

Comment: And how did you get it running?

Comment: from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know which command you're actually executing so this is just a stab in the dark.

You should not have to provide any input.
Piping the output of the command to cat solves your problem:

```
less testfile.txt | cat
```

Also if your goal is to store the output in another file, you can simply to this (this will overwrite):

```
less testfile.txt > testfilecopy.txt
```

(and this will append):

```
less textfile.txt >> logfile.txt
```

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/how-to-dump-a-man-page

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to check if the process does not support a command-line flag to run in "batch mode", disable paging or something similar which will suppress any such "waits". But I guess you have already done that. Given that you have to enter "-help" interactively tells me it's probably no standard unix command which are usually quite easy to run in a sub-process.

Your best bet in that case would be to use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/). There are python bindings available under [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Expect scripts tend to be fairly ugly, and error-prone. You have to be diligent with error handling. I have only limited practical experience with it as I only modified some of our existing scripts. I have not yet written one myself, but from our existing scripts I know they work, and they work reliably.