# fabric - automate stdin inputs

Tags: python, django, fabric

I know, I want always more!

I am wondering how I can do something like this in fabric:

```
def deploy():
   local('git pull origin dev')
   gitusername = "test"
   gitpwd = "testpassword"
   # here render credentials to stdin so that no need to type in in console

   local('python manage.py collectstatic')       
   confirm_type = "yes"
   # here render 'confirm_type' to stdin so that I dont have to type in console

   local('python manage.py migrate')
   local('/etc/init.d/nginx restart')
```

I thought of `fabric.operations.prompt` but I dont need prompt. I want that fabric reads the credentials from variables and goes on further without asking me anything..

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in fabric's [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html), use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to send data via stdin (used code from "[how do i write to a python subprocess' stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)"):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'collectstatic'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='yes')[0]
```

Remove the stdout, stderr parameters if you want to see the output.

Also, in case of collectstatic you can just specify a --noinput parameter without playing with pipes.

Comment: looks nice, lemme test it