# Execute linux command which requires additional input using Python

Tags: python

**Short version:**
How to execute a linux command which requires input after execution using Python?

---

**Long version:**
I am building some fancy website stuff using Python to give my SVN server a way to be managed easier. (I can't remember all the linux commands)

So I want to create, delete and edit repo's and users using a webpage. I just came to the problem I do not know how to execute the following command using Python:

```
sudo htdigest /etc/apache2/dav_svn.htdigest "Subversion Repo" [username]
```

Well I know how to execute the command with `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen()`, but the problem is that once that command is executed it asks to enter a password twice before continuing. Using multiple calls using `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen()` won't work since they just create a new shell.

Is there a way in Python to let an argument be used once it is required?

Comment: *ssh* reads input from the terminal, which means that solutions using stdin are harder.  You may want to look into *sshpass* which will read a password from stdin (or, MUCH LESS SECURELY, can take it as a command line argument).

Comment: Running sudo from inside an automated script is not the recommended way of elevating privileges, but if you really want to do it, have you tried sending some `stdin` into the `Popen`?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` does not have to open a new shell, by the way;  it can run the executable directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i write to a python subprocess' stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)

Comment: Did not know that Popen could also 'reply' on the results. Maybe time to read full documentation. :) Thanks for the replies. Still have some issues with using communicate and the expecting string for password, so going with pexpect for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends, you can either use popen and handle bidirectional communication or if you are just waiting for known prompts, I would use pexpect:

So assuming, you wanted to spawn a program called myprocess and waited for the password prompt that had a > (greater than sign):

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('myprocess')
child.expect('>')
child.sendline(password_var)
child.expect('>')
child.sendline(password_var)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting pexpect! It works like a charm.