# How do I create a python subprocess using a file for stdin starting at a certain line?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like the following to print 3 and 4:

input.txt

```
1
2
3
4
```

program1.py

```
import subprocess
inputfile = open('input.txt', 'r')
inputfile.readline()
inputfile.readline()
subprocess.call('python program2.py',stdin=inputfile)
inputfile.close()
```

program2.py

```
while True:
    print raw_input()
```

It will print nothing. But if I remove the readlines() it will print 1 through 4 just fine.

How can I use a file starting at a certain line for a stdin for a subprocess?

Comment: I believe the answer provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Popen()` and `.communicate()` instead of `call()` . I am not completely sure why `call()` does not work in your case, but the following would work -

program1.py

```
import subprocess
import sys
inputfile = open('input.txt', 'r')
inputfile.readline()
inputfile.readline()
p = subprocess.call(['python', 'program2.py'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate(inputfile.read())
inputfile.close()
```

`.decode()` is needed as `communicate()` expects byte string, not normal string. I also redirected the `stdout` for the process to the `stdout` of your script, so that the results are printed. Also, a better way to write `program2.py` is -

```
import sys
for l in sys.stdin:
    print l
```

This does not cause `program2.py` to go into infinite loop.

---

Example/Demo -

I have two files, `a.py` and `b.py` -

a.py -

```
import subprocess
import sys
inputfile = open('input.txt', 'r')
inputfile.readline()
inputfile.readline()
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python', 'b.py'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate(inputfile.read())
inputfile.close()
```

b.py -

```
import sys
for l in sys.stdin:
    print l
```

Result of running `a.py` -

```
3

4
```