# subprocess.check_call with stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to use

```
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

with the [stdin argument](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call). Most tutorials I've found so far will recommend using `Popen` directly (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475367/353337)), but I really need the exception if `cmd` errors out.

Any hint on how to get

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('patch -p1 < test.patch')
```

to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
subprocess.check_call('patch -p1 < test.patch', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to run the shell, you could pass a file object as `stdin`:

```
with open('test.patch', 'rb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.check_call(['patch', '-p1'], stdin=file)
```