# pass user input to festival

Tags: python, email, security, festival

So I have a Raspberry Pi unit that is set up to check a gmail account and if new mail appears, it reads it out loud via festival.

I interact with Festival via a crude `'echo "' + str(message) + '" | festival --tts'` call where message is the content of an incoming email.

I am guessing that somebody could send something nasty in that message and destroy the computer and I am wondering if there is a good way to clean the message and make the process more safe in general.

I can validate email addresses but, even within validated emails, I want to have any checks I can in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you have to use the shell to invoke festival?
If not, just stay within python and use a lib (e.g. [pyfestival](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfestival/)) for that as this is probably simpler and you don't have the risk of someone injecting shell code into the message.

Update: As you want to call it via a separate process, try it with something like that (not tested yet though)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['festival', '--tts'], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=message)
```

The above is a customized version of that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)'s answer

Comment: I am on a raspberry Pi and I had issues installing pyfestival.  I can read the text from a script via festival but i'm stuck with the command line tool.