# Can I feed lame a blob and have it convert 'on the fly?'

Tags: python, django, bash, lame

I have a situation where a `wav` blob will be posted to my django project and I will have to convert it to an mp3. I have the process down, but it seems a little verbose and I would like to cut it down a bit but IDK how to go about doing it.

```
wav_path = os.path.join(full_path, "%s%s.wav" % (word.name, file_number))
mp3_path = wav_path[:-3] + "mp3"
with open(wav_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(request.FILES['audio_file'].read())
    os.popen("lame %s --comp 40 %s" % (wav_path, mp3_path))
    os.popen("rm %s" % wav_path)
```

lame says it can take something from stdin instead of a named file with `-` so I tried this

```
lame - --comp 40 outfile.m3p << infile.wav
something infile.wav | lame - --comp 40 outfile.mp3
```

Sorry for adding `something` there but I am unsure of what to use in that spot. It seems like writing the blob to a file > converting it and then deleting the blob can be shortened up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace 'something' with 'cat' in your example.

```
cat infile.wav | lame - --comp 40 outfile.mp3
```

But in case you already have the blob in python, you could directly pipe it via stdin, instead of going the detour of writing it to a .wav file. See
[How do I write to a Python subprocess' stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)