# How to give input to exe file using subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have opened an exe in python using this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["E:\ApkTool.exe"])
```

this executed the application in python. the application has its own menu which requires 1-7 digit input. i want to give this input to application from python.

My inputs are:

```
first input : 2
second input : 1
last input : y
```

please guide me how i can do it using python?

Comment: Also, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: @fredtantini i am a newbee to python can you please guide me in easy words ?