# Elixir/Erlang: Communication with external process

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

Say I have a simple python script which executes an elixir/erlang script using the `subprocess` module.

Say the OS PID of the python script is `P1` and that of the spawned elixir/erlang script running is `P2`.

I want to know if communication  between `P1` and `P2` is possible. More specifically, `P1` writes something to the `stdin` of `P2`, and `P2` reads the received input from `P1` and writes some corresponding output to its own `stdout` and `P1` reads from the `stdout` of `P2` and again writes something to the `stdin` of `P2` and so on.

I know the other way is possible, i.e., spawning external process from inside elixir/erlang and then communicating with the process. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sure, why not? Just read from Elixir using `IO.gets` (or similar) and write using `IO.puts` (or similar) and do the reverse in Python (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)? Did you try this?

Comment: Thanks! What if `P1` was an elixir process as well?

Comment: You can use Ports instead of subprocess. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html

Comment: You could use two named pipes, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this sort of cross-language IPC is entirely possible.  The vast majority of the documentation and blog posts and such (and the responses so far here on StackOverflow!) assume the opposite of what you seem to be asking - that is, they assume that Erlang/Elixir is spawning the Python subprocess, rather than Python spawning an Erlang/Elixir subprocess.  If that's okay (i.e. you're okay with your Erlang or Elixir app spinning up the Python process), then great!  Badu's answer will help you do exactly that, and you could also have a gander at [the documentation for Elixir's `Port` module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html) for an extra reference.

But that doesn't seem to be the answer you seek, and that's less fun.  The world needs more documentation on how to go the other way around, so let's dive into the wonderful world of running Erlang as a subprocess of a Python script!

First, our Python script (`eip.py`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

erl = Popen(['escript', 'eip.escript'],
            stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
ping = input('Ping: ')

outs, errs = erl.communicate(input=ping.encode('utf-8'),
                                 timeout=15)

print(outs.decode('utf-8'))
```

On the Erlang side (as you might've noticed in that Python code), a really easy way to go about this is to use the `escript` program, which allows us to write more-or-less self-contained Erlang scripts, like this here `eip.escript`:

```erlang
#!/usr/bin/env escript

main(_Args) ->
  Ping = io:get_line(""),
  io:format("Pong: ~ts", [Ping]).
```

Now, when you run `python3 eip.py` and enter `asdf` at the `Ping:` prompt, you should get back `Pong: asdf`.

---

Doing the same thing with Elixir is only slightly more complicated: we need to create a Mix project with a bit of extra configuration and such to tell Mix to put together an escript file.  So let's start with the project:

```
$ mix new eip
* creating README.md
* creating .formatter.exs
* creating .gitignore
* creating mix.exs
* creating lib
* creating lib/eip.ex
* creating test
* creating test/test_helper.exs
* creating test/eip_test.exs

Your Mix project was created successfully.
You can use "mix" to compile it, test it, and more:

    cd eip
    mix test

Run "mix help" for more commands.
```

(It's probably overkill to even use Mix for this simple example, but I'm assuming you'll eventually want to do something more advanced than this example)

Next, you'll want to add an `escript` option to your `mix.exs`, like so:

```
defmodule Eip.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project, do: [
    app: :eip,
    version: "0.1.0",
    elixir: "~> 1.9",
    start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
    deps: deps(),
    escript: escript()
  ]

  def application, do: [extra_applications: [:logger]]

  defp deps, do: []
  defp escript, do: [main_module: Eip]
end
```

And finally, your `lib/eip.ex` module:

```
defmodule Eip do
  def main(_argv) do
    ping = IO.gets("")
    IO.puts("Pong: #{ping}")
  end
end
```

And now we just need to build it:

```
$ mix escript.build
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated eip app
Generated escript eip with MIX_ENV=dev
```

`eip.py` will need a slight adjustment to point to this new Elixirified ping/pong IPC thingamabob:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired

erl = Popen(['escript', 'eip/eip'],
            stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
ping = input('Ping: ')

outs, errs = erl.communicate(input=ping.encode('utf-8'))

print(outs.decode('utf-8'))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't *entirely* work:

```
$ python3 eip.py
Ping: asdf
Pong: eof
```

The same results happen even when using a more direct port of the Erlang version (i.e. replacing `IO.gets("")` with `:io.get_line("")` and `IO.puts("Pong: #{ping}")` with `:io.fwrite("Pong: ~ts", [ping])`, which means something specific to Elixir's STDIN handling in general is causing it to prematurely believe it's reached end-of-file.  But hey, at least one direction works!

Answer (score 0):

Like Dogbert said, you can use Ports instead. Check out [Erlport](http://erlport.org/)
and [here](https://hackernoon.com/mixing-python-with-elixir-7a2b7ac6696) is a blog post on communicating between Elixir and Python