# Passing value from input() to another python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass a username and password `input()` variables from a master script to a different script. However, when the next script runs it asks me for the `input()` again rather than passing through the string value.

MasterScript.py

```
Username = input('Enter Username: ') 
Password = input('Enter Password: ') 

print('Running First Section')
import Firstsection
```

SectionOne.py

```
import cx_Oracle
from MasterScript import (Username, Password)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(Username, Password, "myurl.co.uk:1234 /abcd1")
```

Once section one is called via the MasterScript.py it asks me for the username and password again, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of OS are you running? In linux you can do it via `piping`. Or you can create a simple socket/rest controller for receiving data.

Comment: I'm just using standard windows

Comment: It's almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: Hmmm seems quite complex I'll try and give it a go. Shame there isn't a more simple process, I'll get back to you.