# How to write to stdin more than one times in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, fcntl

I create a subprocess in python3.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('./a', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And I want to write to it stdin.

```
p.stdin.write('1\n')
do_something()
p.stdin.write('2\n')
```

But python only support write once. What should I do?
Should I use fcntl and how to use it?

Comment: Another option would be to use `communicate` as explained in [this question's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin).

Comment: `communicate` can be called only once and it wait for subprocess.

Comment: Should use `flush()` after `p.stdin.write()`