# How to keep ssh connection open and doing multiple requests and outputs within python

Tags: python, ssh

Because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887790/how-to-keep-ssh-session-open-after-logging-in-using-subprocess-popen) seems to aim somewhere else I am going to point my problem here:

In my python script I am using multiple requests to a remote server using ssh:

```
def ssh(command):
  command = 'ssh SERVER "command"'
  output = subprocess.check_output(
    command, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True,
    universal_newlines=True
  )
  return output
```

here I will get the content of `file1` as `output`.

I have now multiple methods which use this function:

```
def show_one():
  ssh('cat file1')

def show_two():
  ssh('cat file2')

def run():
  one = show_one()
  print(one)
  two = show_two()
  print(two)
```

Executing `run()` will open and close the ssh connection for each `show_*` method which makes it pretty slow.

Solutions:

1. I can put:

```
Host SERVER
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist yes
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%p
```

into my `.ssh/config` but I would like to solve this within python.

2. There is the ssh flag `-T` to keep a connection open, and in the before mentioned Question one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948768/4602919) was to use this with `Popen()` and `p.communicate()` but it is not possible to get the output between the `communicates` because it throws an error `ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication`
3. I could somehow change my functions to execute a single ssh command like `echo "--show1--"; cat file1; echo "--show2--"; cat file2` but this looks hacky to me and I hope there is a better method to just keep the ssh connection open and use it like normal.
4. What I would like to have: For example a pythonic/bashic to do the same as I can configure in the `.ssh/config` (see `1.`) to declare a specific socket for the connection and explicitly open, use, close it

Comment: Did you consider creating an SSH object and passing it to the functions ? so you will always have 1 connection open and you pass it tp the functions who need it.

Comment: this is something I have in mind, but how to `create an SSH object` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create ssh object from class and pass it to the functions:

```
import paramiko
from pythonping import ping
from scp import SCPClient

class SSH():

def __init__(self, ip='192.168.1.1', username='user', password='pass',connect=True,Timeout=10):
    self.ip = ip
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.Timeout=Timeout
    self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    if connect:
        self.OpenConnection()
        self.scp = SCPClient(self.ssh.get_transport())

def OpenConnection(self):
    try:
        skip_ping = False
        ping_res=False
        log.info('Sending ping to host (timeout=3,count=3) :'+self.ip)
        try:
            PingRes = ping(target=self.ip,timeout=3,count=3, verbose=True)
            log.info('Ping to host result :' + str(PingRes.success()))
            ping_res=PingRes.success()
        except:
            skip_ping=True
        if ping_res or skip_ping:
            log.info('Starting to open connection....')
            self.ssh.connect(hostname=self.ip, username=self.username, password=self.password, timeout=self.Timeout, auth_timeout=self.Timeout,banner_timeout=self.Timeout)
            self.scp = SCPClient(self.ssh.get_transport())
            log.info('Connection open')
            return True
        else:
            log.error('ssh OpenConnection failed: No Ping to host')
            return False

myssh = SSH(ip='192.168.1.1',password='mypass',username='myusername')
```

the ping result is wrapped in try catch because sometimes my machine return an error you can remove it and just verify a ping to the host.
The self.scp is for file transfer.

Comment: ok there is a lot of verbose code, but I guess the important thing here is that you suggest to use the `paramiko ssh client` I will try if this solves my question here

Comment: Yes the basic is paramiko