# How to enter any key to get full output of openssl command using subprocess module python

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess

Not able to get full output as need to give input GET / or enter in between command execution(interactive mode).

Output :
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is AES128-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA256
    Session-ID: 5054E5886B691DDC3020D84F85F97E4A439AC51999141AB05FB22EC2F7EAA533
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 5B13A9AEBBCA9C014D36E831C9319ABE0FF5009ED4CE584E8BFE3FAC18EAD1B49E4FF164826F06AA6323105B3B72BA20
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1576061327
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)

### Extended master secret: no

### then need to give enter to get:

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: Close
Location: http://192.168.1.110

http://192.168.1.110 ">

This page requires higher encryption. Please click [here](http://192.168.1.110%20)  to continue

closed

```
cmd = r"openssl s_client -connect site.com:8080 -CAfile C:\\Users\\dbansal\\Desktop\\dad_hacks\\client_auth\\two_level_rootCA.pem
 -cert client_1024.crt.pem -key client_1024.key.pem -cipher AES128-SHA256"
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
import time
time.sleep(4)
p.terminate()
out, err = p.communicate()
out = out.decode()
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: thanks for reference