# Is there a Python function to automatically answer yes on prompt in Windows 10 Command Line?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

I want to use Python to execute this command in Windows 10 command-line:

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" connect [some_server]**

and after that to automatically answer **"y"** on **"Connect Anyway"** prompt. Which is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write to a Python subprocess' stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)

Comment: If you clarify how you are calling that command in Python code, commenters might be able to help you more specifically.

Comment: Hi @NilsGuillermin. Thank you for the suggestion. I just modified my question slightly.

Comment: @DCupovic I was thinking more along the lines of you posting the Python code you're using in your question.

Comment: In any case, if the command you're running doesn't have an option to skip the prompt (sometimes that's a `-y` or a `--force`), you could try piping in an `ECHO 'yes'` by using a pipe, so it would look something like `ECHO "yes" | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" connect [some_server]`

Answer (score 0):

This should run the exe file and send a "y" upon running it.

```
os.system('cmd /c' "echo y | C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe")
```