# Python subprocess.Popen not working with flask

Tags: python, linux, flask, subprocess

I have this script running as root:

```py
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['chpasswd'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("username:password")
print("Password updated")
```

While the script is run as a root user, it works as expected.

However, when I try running it under `flask`, it prints `"Password updated"`, but it does not actually update the password.  What could be the reason, and how to make it work?

```py
...
@app.route('/')
def some_path():
    if condition:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['chpasswd'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        proc.stdin.write("username:password")
        print("Password updated")
...
```

Comment: Why do you expect `chpasswd` to work in unprivileged mode at all? Run it with `sudo`, or have Flask talk to a privileged helper. (Also, probably use `subprocess.run()` if your Python is new enough, or `subprocess.check_call()` if you need to support dead versions.)

Comment: I am running the script as root, @tripleee

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475367/4956059), replacing `proc.stdin.write("username:password")` with `proc.communicate(b"username:password")` solves the problem.