# injecting passphrase for ssh key using subprocess - python - windows

Tags: python, windows, ssh, subprocess, passphrase

Im writing a script for automatic connection and command execution via internet. I want to connect to my raspberry using this script:

```
def establish_connection(cmd=" ssh pi@00.0.000.000", *args):
   passphrase = "my_passphrase "
   proc = subprocess.popen(cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

   # at this point "Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\.../id_rsa':" pops out in the therminal and im not able 
   # to pass that passphrase
```

I have tried many things but couldn't find the right answer that would work on Windows

Comment: One solution is to make yourself an SSH key that doesn't require a passphrase. Another is to set up an SSH-Agent that the ssh command will access to get credentials (you probably need to type in your passphrase once, to the agent, but not later on).

Comment: Sorry, I have no access to Windows machine yet, but have you tried solutions from this question? It's quite similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: Yes, and it seems like SSH doesn't want to communicate

PS: and yes, I thought about setting a key without passphrase, but at this point i just need to find that damn solution