# How can you bypass an input prompt in Python3 when there is no option to skip the input?

Tags: python, input

Using a library that when I call a certain function that I will call `foo()` , I am prompted for input as such:

```py
def foo():
   if input("Proceed?") == 'yes':
        take_action()
```

I am required to pass in an answer to continue.

But I would like to be able to loop over `foo()` with a default value to feed the prompt.

The problem is the developers did not provide an option to supply a default value for the prompt.

Ideally they would have written `foo()` like this:

```py
def foo(default_response=None):
    if default_response == 'yes':
        take_action()
    elif input("Proceed?") == 'yes':
        take_action()
```

Given that they did not supply an option for a default response, is there a way for me to loop over `foo()` and provide the input automatically without changing the source code?

Comment: Why can't you just write your own function that does only what you need? A messy solution might be to run it in a subprocess and provide the input as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin

Comment: That's why [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) exists :-)

Comment: Ideally, the function wouldn't call `input` *at all*, and rely entirely on the caller to provide the necessary input. I/O should happen as close to the "edge" of the program as possible.

Comment: @Stuart Writing my own function would really just be duplicating most of their original function in my library. Trying to avoid copying code when I just need to change a small part of it.

Comment: @KellyBundy trying to avoid OS specific solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the library to temporarily replace the `input` function. For example, if I have module `foo.py` that looks like this:

```
def take_action():
    print("doing something")


def foo():
    if input("Proceed? ") == "yes":
        take_action()
```

I can write `bar.py` like this:

```
import foo
from unittest import mock


def fake_input(default_response=None):
    '''Creates a replacement for the `input` function that will
    return a default response if one was provided.'''

    def _input(prompt):
        return default_response if default_response else input(prompt)

    return _input


with mock.patch("foo.input", new=fake_input("yes")):
    foo.foo()

foo.foo()
```

If you run this code, you'll see that the first call to `foo.foo()`
uses a default input, and proceeds without prompting. The second call
to `foo.foo()` will prompt normally.