# bash PIPE equivalent in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am converting a `bash` script into `python` script. In the bash script there is one section that basically sends mail like

```bash
( echo "some_body"
  echo "some header"
 ) | ./sendmail to_user@mail.com
```

I am trying to convert it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['./sendmail', 'to_user@mail.com'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='data_to_write')[0]
```

But I am not sure how to pass multiple inputs like in the multiple `echo` shown in the bash script.

**Additional Question:**

Apart from this, I have one more question, in the bash scripts there is one command always on top, like

```bash
. /opt/../some_necessary_exports.sh
.
.
. other stuff
```

here `some_necessary_exports.sh` is like

```bash
export SOMETHING="some_thing"
export SOME_OTHER_THING="some_other_thing"
.
.
.
```

In the python script, I am calling Linux commands using the subprocess module like--

```py
p1 = Popen(['bash', 'some_necessary_exports.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

p2 = Popen(['bash', 'other_command'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

p3 = Popen(['bash', 'other_command'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

I am not sure if these exports will be persisted in other commands. What will be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate the strings you want to send with newline between them.

```
stdout_data = p.communicate(input=some_header + "\n" + some_body)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, can you provide some suggestions for the second question?