# How do I write to a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-devops, subprocess, azure-cli

I'm trying to write a Python script that starts a subprocess to run an Azure CLI command once the file is executed.

When I run locally, I run:

```
az pipelines create --name pipeline-from-cli --repository https://github.com/<org>/<project> --yml-path <path to pipeline>.yaml --folder-path _poc-area
```

I get prompted for an input which looks like:

```
Which service connection do you want to use to communicate with GitHub?
 [1] Create new GitHub service connection
 [2] <my connection name>
 [3] <org name>
Please enter a choice [Default choice(1)]:
```

I can type in 2 and press enter then my pipeline is successfully created in Azure DevOps. I would like to run this command being dynamically entered when prompted.

So far I have tried:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'az pipelines create --name pipeline-from-cli --repository https://github.com/<org>/<project> --yml-path <path to pipeline>.yaml --folder-path _poc-area
cmd = cmd.split()

subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

This will run in the exact same way as when I try to run it locally.

Try to follow answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin) I have also tried:

```
p = subprocess.run(cmd, input="1", capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
print(p)
```

Which gives me an error saying `raise NoTTYException(error_msg)\nknack.prompting.NoTTYException`.

Is there a way where I can execute this Python script, and it will run the Azure CLI command then enter 2 when prompted without any manually intervention?

Comment: So, not interested by the answer I gave ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. [`az pipeline create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-create) takes a `--service-connection` parameter. You don't need to respond to the prompt, you can provide the service connection value on the command line and skip the prompt entirely.

Comment: When I add the `--service-connection` parameter with the exact same service connection value that shows up in the prompt when running locally, I get an error saying `Could not create service hooks subscription. The repository does not reference a service connection.`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, Daniel is right, you're not supposed to deal with stdin in your program.
Nevertheless, if you really need to, you should use `pexpect` package, which basically opens a process, waits for given output, and then sends input to the process' stdin.

Here's a basic example:

```py
import pexpect
from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn

cmd = 'az pipelines create --name pipeline-from-cli --repository https://github.com/<org>/<project> --yml-path <path to pipeline>.yaml --folder-path _poc-area'
child = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('cmd', timeout=1)
child.expect ('.*Please enter a choice.*')
child.sendline ('2')
# child.interact()     # Give control of the child to the user.
```

Have a look at `pexpect` documentation for more details. MS Windows support is available since v4.0.

Another archaic solution would be to use subprocess the following way, emulating basically what expect would do:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

p = subprocess.Popen(azure_command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
sleep(.5)
stdout = p.communicate(input=b'2\n')[0]
print(stdout.decode())
```

Still, best solution is to use non-interactive mode of most CLI programs.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. As I am on a Windows machine, using the `pexpect.spawn()` command gives me an error saying `AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'`. When I use the alternative way I get: `  File "C:\Python381\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Too bad bounty is gone. What version of pexpect did you install ? As for the alternative, depending on your command, you will have to add `shell=True` for PATHS variable to exist. Also try to run with UAC for sake of sanity.

Comment: Updated my example above, just tested it using`cmd.exe` as command then sending `ipconfig`. Works good.